# System.out.println() not printing anything.

Tags: java, function, terminal, println

This code compiles, but doesn't print anything into the terminal.

So my code is meant to compare the y co-ordinate of the robot with the y co-ordinate of the target.

```
public class Ex12 
{

  private byte isTargetNorth(IRobot robot)
  {

    if (robot.getLocationY() > robot.getTargetLocation().y) 
      {System.out.println("north");
      return 1;}

    else if (robot.getLocationY() == robot.getTargetLocation().y)
      {System.out.println("no");
      return 0;}

    else 
      {System.out.println("south");
      return -1;}

  }
}
```

Comment: You just compile this class ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Do you have more code than this?

Comment: Do you have a main method that calls this one?

Comment: Aside from anything else, your code would be easier to read with more conventional formatting. There are a few different common conventions, but this isn't any of them.

Comment: How do I call this method in my main method?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is supposed to be:

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{

     IRobot robot = new IRobot().

     Ex12 instance = new Ex12().

     instance.isTargetNorth(robot);


}

   public class Ex12 
{

  public byte isTargetNorth(IRobot robot)
  {

    if (robot.getLocationY() > robot.getTargetLocation().y) 
      {System.out.println("north");
      return 1;}

    else if (robot.getLocationY() == robot.getTargetLocation().y)
      {System.out.println("no");
      return 0;}

    else 
      {System.out.println("south");
      return -1;}

  }
}
```

Comment: No, it isn't.  



robot.getLocationY() is a function that returns the y co-ordinate of the robot.  



robot.getTargetLocation().y is a function that returns the y co-ordinate of the target.  



robot.getLocationY().x is meaningless. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: @JohnFog You need to create an object in your main, invoking the object in your `byte isTargetNorth(object)`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you just wrote this function and you aren't calling it anywhere.

Make a main with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Create robot instance, assuming a Robot implementation is
    //named Robot and has a default constructor.
    IRobot robot = new Robot();

    //Create instance of example class since your function is not static.
    Ex12 instance = new Ex12();
    instance.isTargetNorth(robot);
}
```

Comment: You're right. I've added this in and I'm getting one error.

TERMINAL SAYS "Ex12.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
    IRobot robot = new Robot();" With an arrow pointing at Robot

Comment: @JohnFog then change your `private byte isTargetNorth(IRobot robot)` to `public byte isTargetNorth(IRobot robot)` and try if it works.

Comment: Do you have a class named Robot?  IRobot is an interface, you need to find a class who's class name says "implements" interface, that means it the class supports the functions that the interface IRobot defines.

Answer (score 0):

You have a method named `isTargetNorth`, but there is nothing that invokes it. You need to invoke the method. Create a `main()` method that invokes `isTargetNorth`. Compile the class, then you can run it from the command line. It's easier if you're using an IDE, though, since it will probably let you run the class from the IDE once you've created the main method. Assuming you have a Robot implementation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IRobot robot = new RobotImpl();
    isTargetNorth(robot);
}
```